# Java Android - Very weird login issue?

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble with this basic Login screen I am making in my Android app, the username I set was "username" and password, "password" for simplicity sake. But when I use an `if` statement to check whether or not the username and password are correct, it returns false.

Code:

```
    typedUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
    typedPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);

    Log.d("Login&Register", typedUsername.getText().toString()); // To make sure I typed it in correctly
    Log.d("Login&Register", typedPassword.getText().toString()); // To make sure I typed it in correctly

    if (typedUsername.getText().toString() == "username" &&
            typedPassword.getText().toString() == "password") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoggedIn.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

What happens in the console

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRsGZ.jpg

I typed it in correctly, but it still returns false and gives me that little toast. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

P.S. If you need to see more code, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check string using **==** you will need to use .equals() method for that and you need only one if statement.

```
 if (typedUsername.getText().toString().equals("username") && 
        typedPassword.getText().toString().equals("password")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoggedIn.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Also make sure you don't have any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things, first you have two ifs here:

```
if if (typedUsername.getText().toString()
```

Next use .equals when comparing strings:

```
if (typedUsername.getText().toString().equals("username") && typedPassword.getText().toString().equals("password")) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoggedIn.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```